# Python: Hide / Delete label when I click on the entrybox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I am trying to hide the labels made with Canvas when I go to click on the entrybox

not when I write but simply on the click
How can I proceed?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_click():

    mainCanvas.itemconfig(1, state='hidden')


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("window")
mainCanvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 300)
mainCanvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)


text_input_name = tk.Entry(window, width = 25)
text_input_name_canvas = mainCanvas.create_window(250, 100, window = text_input_name)
text_input_name.bind("<1>", handle_click)

mainCanvas.create_text(250, 200, text="text", font=("Helvetica", 18), fill="red")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are You creating widgets on canvas? second, You can tag the id of the object on canvas and then bind tag to hiding or sth

Comment: Do you want to hide it _only_ on a click, or do you want to hide it whenever the widget gets focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the solution. Instead of passing `1` you need to pass the `tag/id` of the text. If you want to delete it, use `canvas.delete(tag_or_id)`

Here is an example.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def handle_click(event):

    mainCanvas.itemconfig(text, state='hidden')
    #mainCanvas.delete(text)


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("window")
mainCanvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 300)
mainCanvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)


text_input_name = tk.Entry(window, width = 25)
text_input_name_canvas = mainCanvas.create_window(250, 100, window = text_input_name)
text_input_name.bind("<1>", handle_click)

text = mainCanvas.create_text(250, 200, text="text", font=("Helvetica", 18), fill="red")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: theoretically You could pass in 2 and that would be the same in this case, but for simplicity it is better to just pass it like You have (the id)

Comment: Also for people looking at this in the future, if you hate global variables you can use `.create_text(..., tags=("entry_1", ))` and then `.itemconfig("entry_1", state="hidden")`.